# Call only Get Accessors of property

Tags: c#, asp.net

please tell me how can i call only the get method of this property in another method .
for example

```
 public List<EmployeeData> LOP
        {
            get
            {
                if (_lop == null)
                {
                    _lop = new List<DTPackage>();
                }

                return _lop;
            }
            set
            {
                _lop = value;
            }

        }
```

i want to call only get method of this property.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public List<EmployeeData> LOP
 {
        get
        {
            if (_lop == null)
            {
                _lop = new List<DTPackage>();
            }

            return _lop;
        }
        set
        {
            _lop = value;
        }
 }

var lop = LOP;       // here POP get will be called
LOP = myEmployeeList //here POP set will be called
```

You can make `set` to `private` to avoid access from other classes or remove `set` for readonly

Answer (score 0):

These are all compilable variants of .Net properties:

```
// Shorthand
public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
public string MyProperty2 { get; private set; }
public string MyProperty3 { get; }

// With backing field
private string _myProperty4;
private string _myProperty5;
private readonly string _myProperty6;

public string MyProperty4
{
    get { return _myProperty4; }
    set { _myProperty4 = value; }
}

public string MyProperty5
{
    get { return _myProperty5; }
    private set { _myProperty5 = value; }
}

public string MyProperty6
{
    get { return _myProperty6; }
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt(v=vs.120).aspx)

> Usage:
>
> ```
> string myString = MyProperty4; // Calls get on MyProperty4
> MyProperty4 = "Hello World"    // Calls set on MyProperty4
>
> MyProperty6 = "Hello World"    // Will not be compilable
> ```